# C program to read integers into an Array then print its it

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am new to C programming and I have been trying to make a simple program that reads integers from a .txt file into an array then print it.
The numbers in the file are arranged as follows:

23

44

12

41

123

And this is the code I have been trying:

```
void main()
{
FILE *fp;
int num[100],i,j;
fopen_s(&fp, "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/NUI/fp.txt", "r");



if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Can't open file for reading.\n");
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i<5; i = i + 1) {
        fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &num[i]);
    }

}
for (j = 0; j<5 ; j = j + 1) {
    printf("%d\n", num[j]);
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

In the FOR LOOP I have to write i<5 , j<5 to set number of iterations.But I want to know of there is a way to make the loop recognise the final number automatically.
(Something similar to char[i]!='\0' but for int array)

Comment: `fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &num[i]);` => `fscanf(fp, "%d", &num[i]);` drop this MS-specific crap.

Comment: Just check for end of file. `feof(f)` or `fscanf` return code.

Comment: The function return value from `Xscanf` family is the number of items successfully scanned: in this case `1` indicates success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EOF that means end of file.
In this sample I read the file intFile.txt and print the numbers that I have read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
  int numInt[100];
  int counter = 0;


  fp = fopen ("intFile.txt", "r");

  while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &numInt[counter])!= EOF)
  {
    printf("num = %d\n",numInt[counter++]);
  }
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &numInt[counter])!= EOF)
  {
    printf("num = %d\n",numInt[counter++]);
  }` is an infinite loop should the file contain non-numeric text.  Better to use `while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &numInt[counter]) == 1) ...`